# Is it possible to define views and templates for abstract models to be used for actual models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Let's say I have a `myapp` django app and that I need to define 2 specific contact-related models, e.g.

- `myapp.PersonContact`
- `myapp.CompanyContact`

Somewhat obvious thing to do is to create a new `contacts` app and define an abstract `contacts.Contact` model which can then be reused in `myapp.models`, e.g.:

```
# contacts/models.py
from django.db import models

class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


# myapp/models.py
from contacts.models import Contact

class PersonContact(Contact):
    person = ...

class CompanyContact(Contact):
    company = ...
```

My goal is to abstract as much logic as possible to the `contacts` app but the only thing that comes to mind is to define an Abstract class `contacts.Contact` and use that so that I don't have to redefine the same fields in `myapp.PersonContact` and `myapp.CompanyContact`.

Is is somehow possible to define `contacts.Contact` related views and/or templates within the `contacts` app so that I don't have to create almost identical CRUD-ish views and templates for both `PersonContact` and `CompanyContact`?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Don't generic class based views already do this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Daniel. I guess my question is would I be able to account for the additional field(s) from the concrete models in a way that I do not have to create any views and templates in the `myapp` app (unless I need some custom logic)?